# Why Scala's Try has no type parameter for exception type?

Tags: scala, exception, try-catch, algebraic-data-types

I'm curious why `scala.util.Try` has no type parameter for the exception type like

```
abstract class Try[+E <: Throwable, +T] {
  recoverWith[U >: T](f: PartialFunction[E, Try[E, U]]): Try[E, U]
  ...
}
```

Would help with documentation, e.g

```
def parseInt(s: String): Try[NumberFormatException, Int]
```

Still won't be able to express disjoint exception types like `throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException`, but at least one step in this direction.

Comment: Is your goal to make `Try { foo }` only catch specific exceptions from `foo` as opposed to all exceptions?

Comment: My goal is rather to indicate that a function returning a Try can fail only with a specific exception, not with any Throwable

Comment: Has my answer been relevant in any way?

Comment: yes, I gave it +1. I was mostly curious not in how to overcome it though, but why it's not there in the first place. Like what would be broken in this case.

Comment: Try seems like imperfect in that regard, yes.

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._
import scala.util.{ Success, Failure }

def foo(x: Int): Int = x match {
  case 0 => 3
  case 1 => throw new NumberFormatException
  case _ => throw new NullPointerException
}

val Success(3) = catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]).withTry(foo(0))
val Failure(_: NumberFormatException) = catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]).withTry(foo(1))
// val neverReturns = catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]).withTry(foo(2))
```

See [scala.util.control.Exception$](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception$)

---

However, there's no way to specialize `Try[T]` to something like the hypothetical `Try[ExcType, T]`; in order for that to work you'll need something like `Either` (but possibly something more sophisticated such as [`scalaz.\/`](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Either.html), or, for more than 1 exception class, Shapeless' [`Coproduct`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#coproducts-and-discriminated-unions)):

```
def bar(x: Int): Either[NumberFormatException, Int] = {
  catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]).withTry(foo(x)) match {
    case Success(x) => Right(x)
    case Failure(exc) => Left(exc.asInstanceOf[NumberFormatException])
  }
}

println(bar(0)) // Right(3)
println(bar(1)) // Left(java.lang.NumberFormatException)
// println(bar(2)) // throws NullPointerException
```

---

It should be possible to generalize that into a generic helper that works with any number of exception types. You'd definitely have to work with Shapeless' [`Coproduct`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#coproducts-and-discriminated-unions) and [facilities for abstracting over arity](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#facilities-for-abstracting-over-arity) in that case. Unfortunately, it's a non-trivial exercise and I don't have the time to implement that for you right now.